# Is it possible to dynamically pass the value here --> activity('AcitivityName').output.rowsCopied instead of hardcoding the 'Activityname' in ADF

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-data-factory

I am trying to retrieve the logs of the copy activity. The rowsread and rowscopied, challenge here is I have multiple copy activities and not just one. The goal is to store the logs in SQL server table. Below is the query I am using,

```
****SELECT '@{pipeline().DataFactory}' as DataFactory_Name,
'@{pipeline().Pipeline}' as Pipeline Name,
'@{activity('ActivityName').output.rowsCopied}' as rows Copied,
'@{activity('ActivityName').output.rowsRead}' as Rows Read****
```

I need help in figuring out a way to pass Multiple 'AcitivtyName' in a single command eg : '@{activity('ActivityName').output.rowsCopied}' as rows Copied using foreach.

Comment: We can dynamically pass the value to the SQL query, but the SQL query doesn't support expression.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot tests. We can pass the activity name to the command dynamically. but due to the limitation of the ADF the command cannot be executed.

1. I manually create a string array to store the ActivityName

[image]

2. In the ForEach Activity, I use `@concat('select ''@{activity(''',item(),''').output.dataRead}''')` to dynamically pass the value to the SQL query.

[image]

3. When I run debug, the parameters were parsed but didn't execute the SQL query.

[image]

Hope my answer is helpful to you, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have tried this too. But unable to Parse the Command present in the variable. All I am trying to do is Store the logs of multiple Copy activities in a Single SQL table.

Comment: In my answer, I've  figured out how to pass the activity name to the command. But the command cannot be executed, I think it is a limitation of ADF, so we cannot achieve that.  If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: I have tried this solution beforehand itself. I am now able to retrieve the activity logs by using powershell command Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun

Comment: Can you please provide details about how did you achieve this